# Azure SQL scale(vertical) only one shard(from horizontal scaling/partitioning)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, horizontal-scaling

Can I scale vertical(add CPU or RAM) only one particular shard(shard = horizontal partitioning/scaling) ?

I know that whatever partition logic I`ll use, there is a high chance that **one shard will be very big**(I know you can re-partition using Elastic tools, so please avoid alternative comments). 
I imagine that if the shard is on a separate node(VM) than I guess it should be possible ?! 
But how about if all my shards are on one VM, can I give more CPU/RAM to this shard?

Thank you

Comment: Is not clear to what kind of "shards" your a referring to...can you please clarify?

Comment: There is only 1 kind of shard in azure SQL. 
A shard is an individual partition

Comment: Sorry still not clear. Partition in Azure SQL usually refers to table partitioning. Are you refering to that too? Our you are referring to the Elastic Database client library to implement sharding? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-database-client-library

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited the description.
Shard is a node/unit of horizontal partitioning(or horizontal scaling).